# I'm trying to compile the Glade-3 Package under OSX.

Tags: macos, bash, unix, gtk, glade

I downloaded glade-3.19.0 package on OS X, So i followed all the instructions that i needed to install.

I CD'd into glade-3.19.0 package and opened configure file. I installed all necessary packages with Homebrew and exported correct path for pkg.conf.

Configure part went fine, It printed this when it was done:

```
Configuration:

    Source code location:    .
    Compiler:        clang
    Debug Enabled:           no
    GTK+ UNIX Print Widgets: yes
    PYTHON Widgets support:  no
    Gladeui Catalog:         no
    Introspection Data:      no

    Build Reference Manual:  no
    Build Manual Pages:      yes
```

After i finished first step, I tried to compile package with `make`.
and it started printing a lot of errors:

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:413:30: error: unknown type name 'NSString'; did you mean 'GString'?
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
                                 ^
    /usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstring.h:39:33: note: 'GString' declared here
    typedef struct _GString         GString;
```

It was posting all the errors with same message in the same directory.

**Directory**: 
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers`

**Message**: 
`error: unknown type name 'NSString'; did you mean 'GString'?`

Is there anything i need to install or change?

Comment: It could be an issue with clang or homebrew; i used macports and it uses gcc — no issues.

Comment: Please post the complete error log. That one error alone doesn't provide enough information (and isn't even the complete error).